# Resizing cytoscapejs node to fit label inside shape

Tags: cytoscape.js

To size a node to fit the label, cytoscape.js has the special style properties `'width': 'label'` and `'height': 'label'`. When used in nodes with complex shapes, like diamonds en triangles, this does not work very well. `'height': 'label'` will "flatten" the shape too much, but the real problem is `'width': 'label'`, which will calculate the *bounding box* of the shape to fit around the label.

Especially with labels inside the shape (`'text-valign': 'center'`) in shapes like triangles, the bounding box is much wider than the visible border, which makes the label flow over the border:

[image: Node with width: 'label' shows label flowing over the non rectangular form]

Is there a way to size the node enough to fit the label inside the shape? As in: do not calculate the smallest bounding box to fit the label, but resize the largest box that fits *inside* the shape.

Also: when a perfect width is found, is there a way to set the height to also fit the label *and* keep the proportions of the original shape?